# integrating php with bigcommerce api

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I am a newbie to the whole concept of the Bigcommerce Api, but my php programming is good.
I am having problems with identifying where to start exactly if i am going to integrate the php code that I may have created with the bigcommerce api, 
Where do my files go? How do they interact exactly...

On the Bigcommerce site, they define what its all about, and provide the basic php codes.
Google is my friend but she hasn't been able to help me with links for the whole "How to get started" part...

Or maybe I am asking her the wrong questions.

My ultimate task is to take data from an xml file and use php to handle the rest of the processing and displaying..
I am a newbie and I am not sure how it really works. But links to proper tutorials will really help

Comment: Please check answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435222/noobie-bigcommerce-api-connection/29095876#29095876

Comment: Did you just assume Google's gender? *triggered* 
(American meme/joke).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently i had no idea Big-commerce doesn't need me to host any server code on their side or whatever, 
i found out that which ever code i write is simply run on my side so i can interact with my store.
i wonder why i couldn't really find this information anywhere easily, shouldn't it be the first thing we see when we reach the developers page on bigcommerce.com??

Anyway, i found what i was looking for and i understand how it works now.

To begin, as far as where do your PHP scripts go, those will be hosted external to your Bigcommerce store from any server that has PHP installed or from your local computer. The Bigcommerce API basically gives you a way to access and make changes to your store's database using a program. You will interact with API resources endpoints (URLs) which have been tied to specific store related data, like your products or orders. You can make GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE requests on these URLs in order to pull, modify, create, or delete store related data, respectively.
 the php files are here https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php , 
and these should be in your machine with a PHP server
to get started there are sample codes there also.

i had problems with this line

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

so i changed it to

```
require 'path_to_this_file/bigcommerce.php';
```

everything is working fine now... 
but iam still learning more

Comment: Yes, this is how any standard REST or SOAP API works. You need to install and run `Composer` in order for `require vendor/autoload.php` to work, as `Composer` will install all of the required dependencies - meaning other PHP software libraries that the BigCommerce software library may depend on (AKA it calls those files itself via a `require` statement).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [Link](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api) for the list of Resources.

Your php file will be making calls to BigCommerce API, to get data from BigCommerce Store.

Simple cURL snippet to get orders.

```
$api_url = 'https://YOUR-API-PATH.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders.json';
$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Length: 0') );                                   
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "YOUR-USERNAME:YOUR-API-TOKEN" ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );   
$response = curl_exec( $ch );   
$result = json_decode($response); 
print_r($result);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can not make directly call to your store front..for that make request from third party server to get your store Api.

call bellow php code by **Ajax** request...

like that..

----------Php Code:-

```
$username='username';//API User name
$password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';//API Token
$URL='https://store-xxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products';//API path

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:UTF-8','Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  code
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
print_r($result);//Your Requested Data
```

Comment: what is "code" after line status_code ? you should remove it