# Importing Historical Sales Data via API

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm scouting for a business solution, I haven't tried bigcommerce yet but would want to confirm a few things first.

Is there a way to import historical sales data via API? Is there a direct way to do this?

Here are some of the available fields that I'd like to import:

- Date
- Product ordered
- Sale price

Do you think it would work if I create a new product for this, assign the sale price to it, create an Order, assign the previously created product, and lastly mark the order complete? However, I wonder how this would affect my reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can import all orders from BigCommerce using API.

Check [Orders](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders#list-orders) API Call.

Simple PHP cURL [Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246075/integrating-php-with-bigcommerce-api/19248306#19248306) to get orders.

Comment: I already saw the Orders API. Is posting an order the same as posting a sale? More than that, I need to post historical data.