# How to integrate bigcommerce api in php?

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I am newbie in bigcommerce api.
After google search i got code from

[Github bigcommerce php code](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php)

but when i try to test the api in my test script i am getting error

**Fatal error: Class 'Bigcommerce_Api' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\apitest\src\Bigcommerce\test.php on line 7**

my test.php code given below :-

```
            <?php

            require_once 'Api.php';
            Bigcommerce_Api::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
            Bigcommerce_Api::verifyPeer(false);
            Bigcommerce_Api::configure(array(
            'store_url' => 'http://filtersdelivered-com.mybigcommerce.com/',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'api_key' => '26e92a2f6fc3719c1889e78d9c0df7f1402123e9'
            ));
            $products = Bigcommerce_Api::getProducts();

            foreach($products as $product) {
                echo $product->name;
                echo $product->price;
            }

            ?>
```

can any one help me waht i have to do ??

Comment: Can you post your folder structure in C:\xampp\htdocs\apitest\src\Bigcommerce?

Comment: my folder structure same as https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php

Comment: Which PHP version do you use? Try do do a `phpinfo();` at the top of your test.php.

Comment: my php version is 5.5.19

Comment: Ah, so you're up to date.

Comment: then can you pls tell me any other solution ??

Comment: Please check answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435222/noobie-bigcommerce-api-connection/29095876#29095876

Answer (score 0):

It's namespaced. Try adding `use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce_Api;` after your `require_once`.
A complete Copy-Waste solution:

```
<?php

            require_once 'Api.php';
            use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce_Api;

            Bigcommerce_Api::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
            Bigcommerce_Api::verifyPeer(false);
            Bigcommerce_Api::configure(array(
            'store_url' => 'http://filtersdelivered-com.mybigcommerce.com/',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'api_key' => '26e92a2f6fc3719c1889e78d9c0df7f1402123e9'
            ));
            $products = Bigcommerce_Api::getProducts();

            foreach($products as $product) {
                echo $product->name;
                echo $product->price;
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: now warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ;

Comment: Try doing a var_dump($products); instead of the foreach loop to see what the API returns. I suspect that either your credentials are wrong or you don't have any products.

Comment: Try doing `var_dump(Bigcommerce_Api::getProductsCount());` as well.

Comment: i think credentials wrong but after enterd right credentials error Uncaught exception 'Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError' with message 'failed setting cipher list: rsa_rc4_128_sha

Comment: Try removing the setCipher and verifyPeer lines. Looking at the docs, it seems like they're not required.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, remember to revoke your API key when you go live. Right now your API is fully open to anyone reading this thread because you exposed the API-key.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dencker for your help !! i have just transferd code to server and its works.Thanks a lot again

Comment: Great to hear you got it working! Have a nice day, and happy coding :)